# The Coffee Chain

Tags: moc, the-lego-movie

I have been looking all over the internet, since I first came upon the Larry the Barrista minifigure(got into mini figs kind of late), for the coffee chain logo. I love the takehome cup that comes with Larry but I want to make a coffee shop with the coffee chain logo. So far, only one set has a sticker which is 60097 but I would like to know if it is likely that LEGO will be making more things using the Coffee Chain Logo?

[image: 60097 coffee chain]

Answer (score 8):

To the best of my knowledge, this coffee chain logo was made for The LEGO Movie, and then spread to this one set. Noting LEGO's tendencies to use and re-use symbols across themelines (i.e., Octan paraphernalia, Classic Space logo, etc,) I could see some potential for them to include the sticker in a future set. Another real possibility is the long-awaited release of a City Coffee Shop.

If you are looking for ways to make such a custom shop yourself, you might consider making your own stickers using [these techniques?](http://bricksetforum.com/discussion/17857/methods-for-creating-custom-stickers)

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://www.brickbuilderspro.com/the-coffee-chain-instructions-and-sticker-pack/) is somebody that is selling sticker sheets for $11.99 that look like:

[image: sticker sheet]

and you get instructions for building a modular building too.